# loading jquery library from javascript getting error $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have loaded my jquery library in my plug in from javascript and getting an  error **$ is not defined** if I call my plug in anonymous function from another javscript page 
Following is my work

```
(function () {

    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.11.3') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
        // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict();
        // Call our main function
        main();
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
        // Add some validation here to make sure UI is not loaded etc...
        jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js');

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            /******* Load CSS *******/
            var css_link = $("<link>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "StyleSheet.css"
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');

            //loading plug in
            "use strict";
            $.fn.myplugin = function (options) {
                var settings = $.extend({
                    //default
                    isstatic: false
                });
                var options = $.extend(settings, options);
                var images = ['http://www.example1.com'/1.png, 'http://www.example2.com/final.gif'];
                //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
                return this.each(function () {
                    var obj = $('.div2');

                    obj.hide();
                    $(this).show();

                    $(this).click(function () {

                        obj.toggle("slow");
                        if (options.isstatic) {
                            $(".image-class").attr("src", images[0]);
                            options.isstatic = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".image-class").attr("src", images[1]);
                            options.isstatic = true;
                        }
                    });

                });

                return options.isstatic = false;
            }



        });




    }
})();
```

I am calling it using another file.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mydiv').myplugin();

});
```

I am getting an error here **$ is no defined** how to remove this error may b I have done something wrong with jQuery variable or $ in javascript file

Comment: You are using `jQuery.noConflict();` which removes `$` as jQuery's reference. So remove it or you could use `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {...});`

Comment: If I remove it can I use another jquery ui reference that I have added using getscript?

Comment: when I remove jQuery.noConflict(); its giving me error cannot read getscript:( @A.Wolff

Comment: If I use jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {...}); its giving me the same error $ is not defined @A.Wolff

Comment: Inside ready handler, `$` would be `jQuery`

Comment: are u talking about this line jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { or you talking about calling function A. Wolff

Comment: its giving me error on whatever I use in calling function if I write $(document).ready(function (){} its giving e error on $ also If i change it to jQuery(document).ready(function (){} it gives me error on jQuery @A.Wolff

Comment: But your are defining jQuery locally in IIFE (self calling function) scope. You can use `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {/* using '$' here */});` inside IIFE. This is how i understand your issue but missing some context to be sure what's going wrong

Comment: Do i need another javascript file to call my function called myplugin() or not? @A.Wolff

Comment: But firstly, why are you loading jQuery using this snippet? Why don't you load jQuery as usual? And what is `myplugin()`? Where is it defined? Etc... I'm sorry but i'm not sure to understand your expected behaviour

Comment: i am trying to make a plug in and I am asked to use as minimum code as posssible to I am trying to access jquery libraries from javascript so that only a call will be able to embed the desired functionality + few lines of html is there any other way to do this?basically I want to load jquery and jquery ui from javascript along with my plug in code

Comment: thanks for your help any way A. Wolff

Comment: So my best bet is you to unwrap the IIFE's content because anyway jQuery UI needs jQuery to be defined globally

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Comment: am I able to call both javascript libraries after unwrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need jquery for further scripts in your page or for your plugin to run, so jquery reference should be the first one in the head, could you try replacing the part of your code 
`( document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement ).appendChild(script_tag)`

with

`var head=( document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement ); head.insertBefore(script_tag,head.firstChild);`

Comment: thanks mate this worked like a charm!! **** you are a genius**** @user3081756

Comment: can u help me a bit more the error has removed but still if i click on the div another div doesnt toggle it means may be its not loading my jquery library correctly..@ user3081756

Comment: to be specific its loading jquery ui but not jquery correctly because if i add jquery tag in html it works

Comment: I guess [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is what you are looking for. Rather than going for the `ready` function of jquery you can define the functionality under the success of your callback in `getScript`

Comment: thanks you are right but what I have done is mentioned in the links below..  I cant find much over the internet for this but for any body else trying to figure out the same thing these are really helpful http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/ and http://alexmarandon.com/articles/widget-jquery-plugins/